# Comment system which can integrate with existing website

Tags: asp.net, comments

I need third party commenting system for ASP.Net website, preferably free or pay one time fee for the code.

I need the commenting system to be integrate with website login, so that users no need to login again to post comments.

I checked Disqus Single sign on(SSO), however it charges monthly fee for SSO.

Could you suggest any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

you can try
http://livefyre.com/

http://intensedebate.com/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook has an extremely simple commentsystem](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="URL_GOES_HERE" data-numposts="20" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```